# Include plugin in module in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, plugins, module, include

This is a definite newb question:

I have a module defined in my `lib/` directory that I call from a sweeper and as a rake task. Inside the module I want to reference my `spawn` plugin. Just including methods from that plugin doesn't work (undefined method error), nor does any version of require or include that I've tried. What do I need to do to include it?

Thank you!

**EDIT:**

Here is my latest effort:

```
require 'vendor/plugins/spawn/init.rb'

module MyModule

  include Spawn

  def self.my_method

     spawn(:method => :thread, :nice => 9) do # also tried Spawn::spawn

         ...

     end
  end
end
```

The error I get is:

`undefined method 'spawn' for MyModule:Module #spawn` or `undefined method 'spawn' for Spawn:Module # Spawn::spawn`

Answer (score 0):

The including has to be done from within the plugin. When you "reopen" a module (which is in the lib/ dir), remember to require the original file before making changes to it (the module).

EDIT:
Considering that the plugin is third party, you could try:

```
Spawn.module_eval do
  module_function :spawn
  public :spawn
end

module MyModule
  def self.my_method
    Spawn.spawn(...)
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks, mosch. But I don't quite get it. Spawn is a 3rd-party plugin that I'm using to provide functionality for methods in my module. I don't want to add anything to the plugin if I don't have to. Surely there's a way to call Spawn's methods from the module without having to explicitly include the module in the plugin? Tried `Spawn::spawn()` with and without `include Spawn` at the top, etc. Nothing works, though `spawn()` works fine directly in the sweeper.

Comment: I am sorry, didn't know spawn is third-party. But if you look at their init.rb https://github.com/tra/spawn/blob/master/init.rb you can see that they are doing with ActiveRecord::Base what you wanna do with your own module. Try requiring vendor/plugins/spawn/init.rb at the top of your module file and then add "include Spawn" at the first line within the module.

Comment: Still no dice, unfortunately. See my edits. Any other thoughts? I must be missing something simple. (I should say I also tried the `Spawn.send :include, MyModule`, with no luck.

Comment: Updated the answer with another idea.

Comment: That worked to get us into spawn(), but then it chokes on a NoMethodError for the first method (protected) that spawn() calls. Seems strange to have to do all this, right? Do you think there's some environmental config setting/include I need to do to get this to work without all the legwork? I really appreciate your continued help with this!

Comment: You are welcome! I think the easiest way to have it done is to use a class instead of a module within lib/ then the include would work with all the clutter. Is that possible?

Comment: Incredible, but it's the same exact issues as with module. Not sure what to make of this!